# Delphi generic runtime

Tags: delphi, generics, runtime, deserialization

I want to get generic class from deserialization a lot of times.
How can I simplify it?

I know what classes I want to have but I'm lazy and do not want to duplicate the code.

sample:

```
procedure Do;
var 
cl:tclass1;
cl2:tclass2;
..... N classes;
begin
 cl:=tserialization.deserialize<tclass1>(json/xml);
    try
      DoSmthWithMyClass(cl);
    finally
      cl.free;
    end;

  clN:=tserialization.deserialize<tclassN>(json/xml);
    try
      DoSmthWithMyClass(clN);
    finally
      clN.free;
    end;

end;
```

How can I do deserializing my classes for example in Loops?
I know what classes I want to get in advance

Updated:

Real code and error:
[dcc32 Error] uMainForm.pas(68): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Deserialize' that can be called with these arguments

```
for iSupportClass := Low(TSupportedClasses)
      to high(TSupportedClasses) do
    begin
      if db.GetRef(SupportedClasses[iSupportClass].GetTableName, xml,
        error) = 0 then
      begin
//here an error
        iClass := txmlserializer.Deserialize < SupportedClasses
          [iSupportClass] > (xml);

      end;
    end;
```

Comment: You already asked this question once. Why are you asking again? This version is no better. It's completely unclear what you actually want to know.

Comment: It is mini version of the one question. 
And it is common problem.

Comment: @David, I want to throw class type to ...deserialize<here>
In runtime. Dynamic.

Comment: You aren't making it any clearer. Remember that we only have what is here. We don't have the context at all. Use RTTI or a registry. I already told you that multiple times.

Comment: In your last question you agreed to use inheritance. Below is an answer assuming that to be still true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I do something very similar, assuming all classes have common ancestor - in my case TQSI2Common).

```
type
  TSupportedClass = class of TQSI2Common;
  TSupportedClasses = ( scQSI2SessionRequest,
                        scQSI2ErrorReply,
                        scQSI2SessionRequestReply,
                        scQSI2LoginRequest,
                        scQSI2LoginReply,
                        scQSI2CloseSessionRequest,
                        scQSI2CloseSessionReply,
                        scQSI2SiteListRequest,
                        scQSI2SiteListReply,
                        scReportCountRequest,
                        scReportCountReply,
                        scReportAverageTimeRequest,
                        scReportAverageTimeReply,
                        scReportRequest,
                        scReportReply,
                        scGetRecsFromKeysRequest,
                        scGetRecsFromKeysReply );

const
  SupportedClasses : array[ TSupportedClasses ] of TSupportedClass =  ( TQSI2SessionRequest,
                                                                        TQSI2ErrorReply,
                                                                        TQSI2SessionRequestReply,
                                                                        TQSI2LoginRequest,
                                                                        TQSI2LoginReply,
                                                                        TQSI2CloseSessionRequest,
                                                                        TQSI2CloseSessionReply,
                                                                        TQSI2SiteListRequest,
                                                                        TQSI2SiteListReply,
                                                                        TReportCountRequest,
                                                                        TReportCountReply,
                                                                        TReportAverageTimeRequest,
                                                                        TReportAverageTimeReply,
                                                                        TReportRequest,
                                                                        TReportReply,
                                                                        TGetRecsFromKeysRequest,
                                                                        TGetRecsFromKeysReply );
```

You can then look through the supported SupportedClasses array - something like, in your case

```
procedure Do;
var 
  iSupportedClass : TSupportedClasses;
  iClass : TSupportedClass;
begin
  for iSupportedClass := Low( TSupportedClasses) to High(TSupportedClasses)
   iClass:=tserialization.deserialize<SupportedClasses[iSupportedClass]>(json/xml);
    try
      iClass.DoSmthWithMyClass; // this will be an inherited function
    finally
      iClass.free;
    end;
  end; 

end;
```

Obviously this last bit is for illustration purposes only and not tested, but the rest is in real code.

## Edit

The untested code of course does not work, because the generic is a compile time  not a run time action.

Instead you can create a class function to deserialize, like:

```
type
TQSI2Common = class
public
  class function Deserialize : TQSI2Common; virtual; abstract;
  //...
end;

type 
TQSI2Example = class(TQSI2Common)
public
  class function Deserialize : TQSI2Common; override;
end;

//....

class function TQSI2Example.Deserialize : TQSI2Common;
begin
  Result := tserialization.deserialize<TQSI2Example>(json/xml);
end;

//....


procedure Do;
var 
  iSupportedClass : TSupportedClasses;
  iClass : TSupportedClass;
begin
  for iSupportedClass := Low( TSupportedClasses) to High(TSupportedClasses)
   iClass:=SupportedClasses[iSupportedClass].Deserialize;
    try
      iClass.DoSmthWithMyClass; // this will be an inherited function
    finally
      iClass.free;
    end;
  end; 

end;
```

## Edit2

In the context you provided in your new question, generics can be handled, but it is getting a bit messy. The modified class definitions below show this:

```
type
TQSI2Common = class // Note NOT a Generic
public
  class function Deserialize : TQSI2Common; virtual; abstract;
  //...
end;

type 
TQSI2Example<T : class> = class(TQSI2Common)  // note IS generic.
public
end;

type TFirms = class( TQSI2Example<TFirm> )
public
  class function Deserialize : TQSI2Common; override;
end;

type TDiscounts = class( TRefTable<TDiscount> )
public
  class function Deserialize : TQSI2Common; override;
end;
//....

class function TFirms.Deserialize : TQSI2Common; override;
begin
  Result := tserialization.deserialize<TFirms>(json/xml);   
end;
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you. That is that I want!

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not works.

Here is my code:
`code`
 for iSupportClass := Low(TSupportedClasses)
          to high(TSupportedClasses) do
        begin
          if db.GetRef(SupportedClasses[iSupportClass].GetTableName, xml,
            error) = 0 then
          begin
//here an error
            iClass := txmlserializer.Deserialize < SupportedClasses
              [iSupportClass] > (xml);
          end;
        end;
`code`

And  I get an error:
[dcc32 Error]uMainForm.pas(68): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Deserialize' that can be called with these arguments

Comment: @ВиталийТепляков I can't easily read your code in comments. Can you make an edit to your question showing your problem and I will look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Answer  to your edit:
[dcc32 Error] uMainForm.pas(68): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TSupportedClass' and 'Tcommon class'
it is not works :(
Because class of and class are the different classes
But I know that it works fine in my other project...

Comment: Sorry, It works. 
I added a class example instead class type.

Comment: You've accepted this answer, but it doesn't really reduce the amount of code significantly.

Comment: @Dsm.
But I have a mini problem.
I have an SuperArray for my classes like TAncestor<TQSI2Example>
and it is impossible use construct like "class of" Tclass<T>

Comment: @ВиталийТепляков: Why are you still trying to use generics for a problem that does not require generics? The example in the answer does not use any either.

Comment: The problem here is that the question is imprecise and unclear, and so the answer can be at best guesswork. This is why such question should be closed and the asker directed towards asking more clearly. I'm sure there's a good question in here somewhere, but this isn't it.

Comment: @ВиталийТепляков, no, class of TClass<T> is not allowed, but what is T? and is it necessary? It is impossible to answer without knowing what TAncestor is or its purpose. Nor is it pertinent to this specific question. Perhaps you need to create a new question to address this specific problem and this time give us a small program that we can use to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis
bacause I deserializing xml via superobject and in the xml are contained different classes, like:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
 <Reference RefName="Discount">
  <Items>
   <Item Sifr="2" Name="Discount1" Days="5" Deleted="0"/>
   <Item Sifr="3" Name="Discount2" Days="0" Deleted="0"/>
  </Items>
 </Reference>
</Root>
or 
 <Reference RefName="Account">
  <Items>
   <Item Sifr="2" Name="Account 1" Code="5"  Manager="John"  Deleted="0"/>
   <Item Sifr="3" Name="Account 2" Code="0" Manager="Peter"   Deleted="0"/>
  </Items>

Comment: @DavidHeffernan for a couple of classes and for this very simple example you are absolutely right. But when you run into even tens of classes, much less 100, it does save a lot. The top part of the code example is from actual code which has saved me many hours of work and hugely aided readability.

Comment: @Dsm
Ancestor is necessary , because it contains fields like root,reference,items,item to correct deserialization.

Comment: For hundreds of classes this is still going to be very heavy. Way heavier than necessary.

Comment: @ВиталийТепляков That may be true but it doesn't help us. There will be ways around it, but there may be several options and without more specific detail we can have no idea which is best.

Comment: @Dsm, Ok I am ready to provide small program to you to help me.
What will I do?

Comment: @ВиталийТепляков easiest is to create a new question with sample code. You could add it to this question but I think that makes it too specific and harder for other users with a similar issue to find.

Comment: @ВиталийТепляков Sadly your new question has been closed as a duplicate (which I don't think it is), so I will post the solution here with a second edit.

Comment: @Dsm, yes, it works and I already try to use that, but problem it is that:
I want to have some actions with Tarray<T> in case TQSI2Common .
In details see the sample of program

Comment: @ВиталийТепляков Then you should just be able to use normal inheritance for that. In my original example the procedure DoSmthWithMyClass would be a virtual procedure that each class would override to perform the special actions you describe. This might be a conceptual problem for you. You perhaps think of something doing something to a class object, where what you need is for the class to define that action, not the external something.

Comment: @Dsm, Ok, I try it, thank you so much. You appealed with understanding and I appreciate it. Also, sorry for my English :)